# concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor / Multithreading runs out of memory (Killed)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

i am currently working on an supposedly easy web scraping project while learning python. I have a list of about 70MB with a few million IP addresses (sys.argv[1]) that i want to process. Of course, not all of them are reachable.

I am trying to make use of the the concurrent.futures and am currently experiencing memory problems - eventually leading to the whole process being killed.

Now, i have split my futures in two sets (done and not done) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445540/memory-usage-with-concurrent-futures-threadpoolexecutor-in-python3).
I am using about 100 workers (sys.argv[2]) and have 1GB memory available.

I though all done futures would be released once future.results() is called with => futures 1000 done? However, it just seems to be slowing down the process (including the memory being filled until the process is killed).

What am i missing here? Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Thank you in advance.

My code is as follows:

```
import sys
import requests
import concurrent.futures
import urllib3
from lxml.html import fromstring
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

def title(host):
    try:
        url="https://"+host
        r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, timeout=3, verify=False)
        tree = fromstring(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
        title = tree.findtext('.//title')
        print(host+": "+title)
    except:
        pass

max=int(sys.argv[2])
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max) as executor:
    futures_done = set()
    futures_notdone = set()
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        for line in f:
            host = line.strip()
            futures_notdone.add(executor.submit(title, host))
            if len(futures_notdone) >= max:
                done, futures_notdone = concurrent.futures.wait(futures_notdone, return_when=concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED)
                futures_done.update(done)
            for future in futures_done:
                if len(futures_done) >= 1000:
                    future.result()
```

Comment: EDIT: It seems that the threading is slowing down over time. I let the program run for a few hours. I would say the function (title) is running at about 20% of its initial starting speed. Maybe some futures are stuck/ were not released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you are storing done futures in a set without clearing this list later, so it can grow very large. This could be the cause of your memory problem. The `.release()` method of future does not release it, and it is still referenced in the `done_future` list.

Not perfect, but you can try the following. It schedules at most `max` job to be executed concurrently. It periodically gather done jobs and reschedules new jobs. The [idea](https://alexwlchan.net/2019/10/adventures-with-concurrent-futures/) comes from this blog.

The drawback I see in this method is that it must periodically poll the `max` scheduled jobs to find the ones that are done, this could be slow with large `max` values.

```py
import sys
import requests
import concurrent.futures
import urllib3
from itertools import islice
from lxml.html import fromstring
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


def title(host: str) -> str:
    try:
        url="https://"+host
        r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, timeout=3, verify=False)
        tree = fromstring(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
        title = tree.findtext('.//title')
        return host+": "+title
    except:
        pass

max = int(sys.argv[2])

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max) as executor:
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        futures = {executor.submit(title, h) for h in islice(f, max)}
        
        while futures:
            done, futures = concurrent.futures.wait(
                futures, return_when=concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED)

            for future in done:
                print(future.result())

            for h in islice(f, len(done)):
                futures.add(executor.submit(title, h))
```

---

Here is a workaround that may work for you, It ran for more than 1 million iteration without using more than 150 Mo on my computer.

It is simply a custom thread pool with two queues to manage concurrent ressources access and to limit the maximum concurrency.

```py
import sys
from typing import Optional
import requests
import urllib3
from lxml.html import fromstring
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread


def get_title(host: str) -> Optional[str]:
    try:
        url = f"https://{host}"
        r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, timeout=1, verify=False)
        tree = fromstring(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
        title = tree.findtext('.//title')
        return f"{host}: {title}"
    except Exception:
        return None

class Pool:
    def __init__(self, work, max_concurrent_jobs, max_worker: int = 32) -> None:
        self.max_workers = max_worker
        self.work_queue = Queue(max_concurrent_jobs)
        self.out_queue = Queue()
        self.is_running = True

        def _work():
            while self.is_running:
                item = self.work_queue.get()
                result = work(item)
                self.work_queue.task_done()
                self.out_queue.put(result)

        for _ in range(max_worker):
            Thread(target=_work).start()

    def close(self):
        self.is_running = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_name = sys.argv[1]
    max = int(sys.argv[2])
    pool = Pool(work=get_title, max_concurrent_jobs=max)

    def worker():
        while True:
            item = pool.out_queue.get()
            if item is not None:
                print(item) # Or any follow-up job
            pool.out_queue.task_done()

    Thread(target=worker, daemon=True).start()

    with open(file_name) as f:
        for h in f:
            pool.work_queue.put(h.strip())
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237891/discussion-on-answer-by-louis-lac-concurrent-futures-threadpoolexecutor-multit).